# Are std::list::splice() and std::forward_list::splice_after() declared as noexcept in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, splice, stdlist, forward-list

Cppreference mentions nothing about the exception guarantee of [`std::forward_list::splice_after()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/splice_after) and  [`std::list::splice()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice).

However, since these 2 functions only change the pointer of the list node and thus do not need to `copy`/`move` any elements or allocate any memory, IMHO they should be `noexcept`.

Are they `noexcept` in `C++11`? If they are not, why not?

Comment: splice and splice_after just fiddle around with pointers. I looked at the implementation and that's really all they do. I'm not quite sure why they aren't marked as noexcept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All but one has a "*Throws:* Nothing." in the standard and the one that is missing it appears to be an oversight.

They are not noexcept because they are narrow-contract. If you break the (many) preconditions, a debug-mode implementation may want to throw an exception.